# what is the meaning of " much less"?

Tags: transitive-verbs

"I could not afford a bicycle much less a car."

I wanna know what does this word "much less " mean ?

Comment: It's a comparator used to suggest that one item or situation is out of reach, usually financially.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of StackExchange is that you have attempted to answer this question on your own; for example, did you try to look up *[much less](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/much%20less)* in a dictionary? Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 3):

From a native speaker:

Let's say you have a 20% chance of affording a bicycle, and only a 1% chance for a car.  Since your chance of the car is **much less** than your chance of the bicycle, you say "I could not afford a bicycle, **much less** a car."

As in a good part of American English, the sentence compresses a longer thought that the reader or listener will understand: "I could not afford a bicycle, *and certainly there is* **much less** *chance I could afford* a car."

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph, but you ought to know that this is not something unique to "American" English.